# Trying to remove nested tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="item">
     <div class="appIcon">
        <img src="img/espn-hex2.png" alt="ESPN" />
    </div>
    <div class="appDetails">
        <h2>ESPN<small> SUMMER 2013, Bristol, CT</small></h2>
        <p class="info">I was chosen for a Summer 2013 internship at ESPN, in Bristol, Connecticut. This was a dream come true opportunity for me since it combined my love of sports with my love of web development. I was part of the dotcom team which maintains the overall website. Specifically, I was part of the live events team. We handled creating pages for live games, home run derby, the Sportscenter mobile app, and many other things.</p>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to generate slider indicator tooltips dynamically based on the `<h2>` text (just so I don't have to maintain this infinitely long list). I am only interested in the text leading up to the `<small/>` tag though. I tried doing the following:

```
$(".item").eq(count).find("h2").clone().find("small").remove().text(); //count is for loop iterator to loop through all slides
```

This, however didn't work. I am not terribly advanced in JS, so could someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: what you want to do i am not able to understand question

Comment: also show your complete html i don't see any element with class item

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I want to essentially create a clone of the h2 tag and remove the small tag from within it. so in this example I would just obtain "ESPN." The clone is necessary because I don't want to remove the small tag from the DOM

Comment: it's just a slide item. contains all of the information. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean like:

```
var a = $(".item");
a.find("small").remove();
console.log(a.text());
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb6J3/)

Comment: perfect, thanks! Simple and clean solution!

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like this using [**end()**](http://api.jquery.com/end/):

### HTML

```
<h2>ESPN<small> SUMMER 2013, Bristol, CT</small></h2>
```

### JQUERY

```
console.log($("h2").clone().find("small").remove().end().text());
```

[**EXAMPLE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/vTV6r/)

### UPDATED HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="appIcon">
        <img src="img/espn-hex2.png" alt="ESPN" />
    </div>
    <div class="appDetails">
         <h2>ESPN<small> SUMMER 2013, Bristol, CT</small></h2>

        <p class="info">I was chosen for a Summer 2013 internship at ESPN, in Bristol, Connecticut. This was a dream come true opportunity for me since it combined my love of sports with my love of web development. I was part of the dotcom team which maintains the overall website. Specifically, I was part of the live events team. We handled creating pages for live games, home run derby, the Sportscenter mobile app, and many other things.</p>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

### JQUERY:

```
console.log($(".item").find("h2").clone().find("small").remove().end().text());
```

[**FIDDLE WITH UPDATED HTML**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/b3xU8/)